# Trying to print 'X' pattern string

Tags: c, string, pattern-matching

Below is my final code but no output has been printed in the console. Please help me to find the mistake.

```
#include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>

    int main()
    {
        char s[10] = "Gokul";
        int len = 0;

        while(s[len] != '\0');
        len++;

        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < len; j++){
                if(j==i || j == (len-i-1)){
                    printf("%c", s[i]);
                }
                else printf(" ");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `while(s[len] != '\0');` -> `while(s[len] != '\0')`. That is, remove semi-colon.

Comment: You may want to consider how you could have better debugged this issue to find the problem yourself. The best way to do that is to run your program in a debugger. And even basic debug print statements should have lead you easily to that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 while(s[len] != '\0');
 len++;
```

Mistake is here.
The body of your loop is *empty*
Next time, use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the statement

```
while(s[len] != '\0');
```

is

```
while (s[len] != '\0') {

}
```

So in your case the statement

```
 while (s[len] != '\0');
 len++;
```

will be expanded to

```
while (s[len] != '\0') {

}
len++;
```

which is wrong based on the logic.

The `len++;` statement should come inside the while condition.

So either you can use like below

```
  while (s[len] != '\0')
    len++;
```

or

```
  while (s[len] != '\0') {
    len++;
  }
```

So I am pasting the working code here

```
#include<string.h>

int main() {
  char s[10] = "Gokul";
  int len = 0;

  while (s[len] != '\0') {
    len++;
  }

  printf("len=%d\n", len);
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
      if (j == i || j == (len - i - 1)) {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
      } else printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps you.